# Elasticsearch Spring Data map mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data

I have problem with configuring my data item that is stored in ElasticSearch.
My structure looks like:

```
public class ElasticPage
{
    private String id;
    private String key;
    private String specCode;
    private String specName;
    private Map<String, ElasticValue> values = new HashMap<>();
}
```

The problem is that when I try to add some annotations to the ElasticValue fields elastic/or spring simply ignores them. For example I have some fields in ElasticValue class:

```
public class ElasticValue
{
    @Field(type = FieldType.String, index = FieldIndex.not_analyzed)
    private String aspectName;
    @Field(type = FieldType.String, index = FieldIndex.not_analyzed)
    private Controls control;
}
```

And I want to make them "not analyzed". But unfortunately they are ignored during the mapping construction. Probably because ElasticValue is used as value in map. If I put ElasticValue directly into ElasticPage (without a map) it works perfectly. Any ideas how I can build it using a map construction?